# Webscraping assistance

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to extract some info from this web page.  I know there are easier ways of obtaining this information yet this is what I am tasked with.  So far, I have been trying this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/qqq/historical'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

From here I am trying to read this directly into a Pandas DataFrame using:

`df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('historical-data__table')))`

However, I am getting this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-94-f3a234b1eafd>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('historical-data__table')))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 916, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 420, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

ValueError: No tables found
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean it's not working?

Comment: @SuperStew I am getting an error: No tables found

Comment: please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Not working is not useful. If there is an error, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58331291/edit) your question and post the full traceback.

Comment: hmm, i tried to scrape the page too but i think its produced via javascript, for this you need to use selenium (i think) best of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data comes from an API which is https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/QQQ/historical?assetclass=etf&fromdate=2019-09-11&limit=18&todate=2019-10-11

You can get it directly using [python-requests](/questions/tagged/python-requests) :

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/QQQ/historical',
    params = {
        'assetclass':'etf',
        'fromdate':'2019-09-11',
        'todate': '2019-10-11',
        'limit': 18
    }
)
print(response.json()['data']['tradesTable']['rows'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your script as is and took a look at the output. 
It seems like the content you're looking for isn't getting pulled which indicates that it's produced via dynamically via javascript. Beautiful soup doesn't have the capability to handle dynamic content as it only can read data that is loaded immediately, unlike javascript which can load content when the document is ready. I would look into selenium.