# How to determine if you need to request from an API or scrape a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I asked this question yesterday: [Webscraping assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331291/webscraping-assistance).

The answer works perfectly, but it leads me to another question, which is how should I have known that this API was available and that scraping the page was completely unnecessary?  Is this information that I can find when inspecting the element?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If a website data appears on another website, it is a high probability that an API is available for that data.  If an API is available, the normal is that you need to sign up for a developer key, and 'pay' in some way for a production key.  There are very few 'free' API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look in the developer console > Network tab and see what requests are made from the website.

Comment: I looked through the console and found it.  Thank you for your help!