# Why is my web scraping producing HTML but won't return any text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

New coder here. I am trying to return all the earnings per share data from this website here:   https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/csco/revenue-eps

I started off slow by just trying to return "March", and used this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/csco/revenue-eps"
response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

month = soup.find("th", {"class": "revenue-eps__cell revenue-eps__cell--rowheading"})

print(month.text)
```

When I run it there are no errors, but nothing is returned.
When I try running the same code but use `print(month)` instead, I return the HTML from the element that looks like the following:
`th class="revenue-eps__cell revenue-eps__cell--rowheading" scope="row"> /th>`

I noticed in the HTML that is returned, that the text isn't inside the `th`. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong or is it the site I'm trying to scrape?

Comment: If you visit that page with JS disabled, that table isn't populated, so I'm guessing that's how your parser is seeing it. My next suggestion would be try to see which Ajax calls are made or which scripts are loaded that load the content you're looking for - you may have to call those directly to get the data instead of looking through the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not embedded in the page but retrieved from an API. You can pass the company name as parameter to get all the data directly :

```
import requests
import json

company = "CSCO"
r = requests.get("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/{}/revenue?limit=1".format(company))

print(json.loads(r.text)['data'])
```

Comment: note that limit=1 gives 2020,2019,2018  limit=2 2017,2016,2015 etc...

Comment: it worked, thank you! Do you know where the documentation for this api could be found? I'm trying to play around with it so I can organize the data a little bit better...

Comment: @RossLeavitt I don't think you will find a documentation unless there is a paid service for these api. I've remembered answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331291/webscraping-assistance/58332112#58332112) which also used this api for other purpose. Feel free to accept the answer if you are good with that